# How to mount container directory to another docker container?

Tags: docker

I have following configuration:

- Host: ubuntu, has docker server running, has directories of apps in `/home/apps/`.
- Container-A: docker:latest, `-v /home/apps:/apps -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`, now it has apps in `/apps`.
- Container-B: python:2.7, `-v /apps/foo:/foo`, one specific app in `/foo`.

Container-A runs Container-B using `docker run` and I need `/apps/foo` to be mounted to Container-B's `/foo`. But it won't, `/foo` is empty.

I believe it's because docker server is running somewhere else (outside of Container-A).

What are the ways of mounting `/apps/foo` to Container-B?

EDIT:

Container-A is running with flags `-v /apps -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`. `/apps` is not mounted from the host. How to mount `/apps/foo` to Container-B in this case?

Answer (score 2):

That is correct.
Since you are using /var/run/docker.sock, even when you run `-v /apps/foo:/foo` from Container-A, the host machine is still the one your docker server runs on.

So you can either create a volume like that: `-v /home/apps/foo:/foo` (from inside Container-A) or setup a secondary docker server inside Container-A.

Comment: It looks like it works. I didn't test because directory `/apps` in Container-A is just a data volume, it's not from host.